# What structure should I chose for my website?

Tags: multisite, customization

I have website with local events and news in our city. There are different categories - one for each of event organizers.

Right now I need to add support for other city - so that user can select one of cities and see events and news from it. It also will be great if I can limit access for author in different cities.

What website structure should I use for that case?

Comment: Define *website structure*

Comment: way of organizing content - how should I organize it to make it easy for editors and users that can easily switch cities

Comment: Keep it simple, organise by PARENT categories and then move down accordingly with taxonomies. Surely a simple dropdown/menu will do? Set a cookie to keep the user on their choice going forward. A good example would be http://www.timeout.com/

Comment: you think that categories are better comparing to multisite?

Comment: Are they separate sites based on single categories or one site with multiple categories?

Comment: There are common articles and separate event and news for different cities

Comment: You could just create taxonomies for events and news (locations, etc), essentially a tag that marks each against a certain city and keep a single WP environment. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies